# Are there any web wallets around with open APIs?

Tags: wallet, development, api, e-wallet

For a long while, blockchain.info offered a web wallet with a convenient web API, but it recently turned out that it now requires an installation to function. I'm wondering - are there any other reputable web wallets out there for developers, with open APIs for sending / receiving coins that don't require an installation of any sorts?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What part of using the API requires installation?

Comment: @karask - https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api "Existing users, beginning January 1st 2016 you will need to complete a brief installation of a local service in order to continue using this API. Please follow the installation instructions below."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `block.io` is a good alternative with full wallet functions. No requirement for NPM or a VPS.